# Node.js How to delete an object which has event listener and free up memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am using `Node.js`. I have an array of `objects`.

```
var my_array = [];
var param_array = [xx, xx, ...];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    my_array[i] = new ClassName(param[i]);

    (my_array[i]).on('event_name', function() {
        // do something
    });
}
```

All the objects are created from a class/library. All the objects have `event listener`.

After finished using the objects in the array, I want to delete all the objects and free up memory.

Based on Google search results, the `Garbage Collector` should automatically free up memory when the memory is not referenced by any variable anymore. So, I set the array to a new empty array:

```
my_array = [];
```

However, I was surprised to find that all the `event listeners` of the objects in the old array are still responding to `events`.

How can I delete (or dereference) all the objects which have event listener and free up memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only clearing your array. There may be a bug in your code, can't tell from the code you posted. To be sure, you should iterate over your `my_arrays` objects and call

> removeListener (‘event_name’, eventListener)

for each, then clear `my_array` using `my_array = []`. In that way, the Garbage Collector will take care of those, as there will be no reference. First argument is event name, second an eventListener you want to delete.

Also, in your case, you should use

> removeAllListeners(‘event_name’)

as it doesn't need eventListener function name and you don't need those objects anymore later.

SSCCE:

```
//creating an EventEmitter object just to illustrate how it works
var events = require('events');

function ExampleObject() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.talk = function()
  {
      this.emit('event_name');
  }
}

ExampleObject.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;

var exampleObject = new ExampleObject();

exampleObject.on('event_name', function() {
    console.log('Here I go!');
  });

exampleObject.talk();
//---------
my_array = [];

var listener = function listener()
{
  console.log('event_name_listener');
}


for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    my_array[i] = new events.EventEmitter();
    my_array[i].on('event_name', listener);
}

for(i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++)
{
    my_array[i].emit('event_name');
    console.log(i);
}

for(i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++)
{
    my_array[i].removeAllListeners('event_name'); //could use removeListener('event_name', listener)
}

my_array = [];
console.log("Array length:"+my_array.length);


//------------- and here our ExampleObject
exampleObject.talk();
console.log("Listeners: "+require('util').inspect(exampleObject.listeners('event_name')));

console.log(exampleObject);//more info

exampleObject.removeAllListeners('event_name');
exampleObject.talk();//nothing happens

console.log("Listeners: "+require('util').inspect(exampleObject.listeners('event_name')));

delete exampleObject;
console.log(exampleObject);
```

Output:

```
Here I go!
event_name_listener
0
event_name_listener
1
event_name_listener
2
event_name_listener
3
event_name_listener
4
Array length:0
Here I go!
Listeners: [ [Function] ]
ExampleObject {
  domain: null,
  _events: { event_name: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  talk: [Function] }
Listeners: []
ExampleObject {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  talk: [Function] }
```

At the end, all eventListeners are deleted.